# "Guilty!" is the name of this game I'm looking for?

Tags: identify-this-game, colpevole

I wanted to know if any kind of SE user is able to identify a certain board game, and to indicate if it exists, at least in its Anglo-Saxon version.
It is an investigation board game, which according to the literal English translation of the title should be called -

**"Guilty!"** -

since I have been told that there is a German version of this game titled: „Schuldig!“.

Obviously, it is not necessary that the exact title is this, and therefore it is good to give other indications to be able to identify this game, which has existed at least since the 1990s.

(however, for clarity, from now on if I have to call this game again during the question, I will call it as said, that is: "Guilty!", exclamation mark included)

In this 4-7 player game, very different from the famous (?) Cluedo or Orient Express -
which they have in common with "Guilty!" just having to deal with an investigation into a crime to be solved -
it is about taking part in a private investigation, but with some peculiarities.
A crime was committed, apparently without explanation. This crime is announced with a specific title, and with specific characters that are part of the story to be released.
But here's the first important difference from the other 2 games above:
- investigators have known since the beginning of the game the identity of the guilty of the crime!
In other words, simulating the typical acumen of a Poirot, rather than  Miss Marple, or Sherlock Holmes, anyway you like, **each of the players already knows from the beginning which of the characters in the story killed the unfortunate victim.**
The investigations in this game focus then not so much on the classic "whodunnit?", but rather on the **mechanics** of the crime - **or the way in which a character was killed** - and above all on **motive** - **the reasons why a character made himself guilty of the crime in question**.
To play this game you need a "*Master*": in other words, one of the players personifies the guilty party. He opens the sealed card of one of the cases to be solved, which contains the plot of the case and all the indications for its resolution, including all the testimonies of the other important characters for the story to be solved: they are friends, family, or simple acquaintances who know something important about the crime.

The player who decides to impersonate the guilty must therefore carefully read the plot of the crime, manage all the cards containing the clues necessary to solve the investigation, and provide all the answers that the characters will have to give to the investigators when they are interrogated.
The answers of the various witnesses are provided ... but based on precise criteria. There are often reasons that prevent witnesses from always answering investigators' questions truthfully, and the case provides various "verbs" - before each testimony, such as "Declare that ...", "Know that ...", or "Admits that ..." - and with which to manage the various testimonies, based on the difficulty with which they can be revealed.
At the end of the game, when most of the clues were discovered, one of the investigators may believe that he has discovered the answers to the two basic questions:
**1) what reasons led the guilty to kill, or what is the motive for the crime**;
**2) how the guilty materially managed to commit the crime, or his mechanics**.
Then, the investigator begins to tell how things went, according to him.
For example, he may say that the guilty acted in revenge against someone, and used a knife to commit the crime.

**If the solution is conceptually correct**, **the investigator who discovered the exact development of the events wins**, and in that case the plot is read to legitimize his victory.
**If the solution is conceptually wrong, however, the investigator is eliminated from the game**.

**If only one investigator remains in play besides the Guilty, the latter is the winner of the game**.

Is there anyone who knows this game and knows how to name it in English?
Thanks for your attention

Comment: What is the language of the version you're familiar with, and what is it called in that language?

Comment: You start by stating that you want us "to identify a certain board game" but, I see no reference in your description to an actual board. Is this not rather a game with clue cards and no board?

Comment: @RobertMiller If I'm reading it correctly, it sounds similar to Clue except with a set of pre-defined scenarios instead of a procedurally generated one (and probably different discover mechanics). Even if there is no "board" it's still on-topic and probably sold next to other board games and tabletop games.

Comment: @ryanyuyu : My point was that it simplifies the search if you can eliminate games that have boards...

Comment: No, no, there is a "board" in his game, and it shows a hypothetical city, with Police, Rover, Airport, Downtown, Park, various other Districts, Beach, Slums, Legal Doctor, and other places where every investigator can go and make various actions.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are only interested in finding an English-language version of the game. Finding a French, Italian, or Spanish version of the game would not interest you?

Comment: Yes, I would know something about an english version of this game,if it exists...

Comment: "Guilty!" it can be played thanks to the sealed and pre-conceived cases, which are inserted in the original package in number of 24 units. Each one  has a title, such as the following: "The Queen of Diamonds"; "Noblesse Oblige"; "Condominium", and various others ... it is also possible to create personalized detective cases, thanks to some deliberately left blank cards that are present in the game package

Comment: I believe this game has been translated into various languages: German, French, Italian, and is therefore entitled from time to time with the literal translation of the english word "Guilty!". Then is, e.g.: "Coupable!" in France; "Colpevole!" in Italy; "Schuldig!" in Deutschland ... and so on ..

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin : How very generous of you! Danke sehr aufmerksam...

Comment: I know very well that the new tag would be used very little;this  because the game is old (90's), and his existance is ascertained in Italian only; therefore, it is assumed that any new tag will be usable by Italian users only, or a few others who know this game - just like Robert, me, and the others in this post. But, since it is a board game, I would like to know if the operation is feasible, in order to find a way to possibly solve various problems related to this fascinating game. Thanks for your patience and devotion.

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin : I just added the tag «colpevole» for you, All that was required was the existence of a question (you supplied one) and editing of the question to type in the new tag. Voilà!

Comment: Ah! You did it before me! In any case, you did well ... you did a great deal of research. Thanks again for the time you spent on this answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Colpevole!** ( meaning Guilty! ) is an Italian-language boardgame, published in 1992. It is easy to find numerous copies of it for sale on eBay.it.
[eBay Italy results for Colpevole!](https://www.ebay.it/sch/i.html?_odkw=gioco%20da%20tavolo&_osacat=233&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=%20colpavole&_sacat=233)

The game's publisher was *Editrice Giochi*, literally *Games Publisher*. They published Parker Brothers games such as *Monopoli, Cluedo, and Risiko!*, a variant of *Risk*.

In 2016, Editrice Giochi was bought out by *Spin Master Corp.*, «... a leading children's entertainment company.»
http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/spin-master-expands-games-portfolio-with-editrice-giochi-purchase-566692661.html

I contacted SpinMaster Corp. by email and by phone, and spoke to a customer agent. This agent did some research and found that the game **Colpevole!** has not been translated to English.

So, the only alternative that I can see for you is to translate the game elements into English yourself.

Here are some screenshots of the games elements. Many more can be found of eBay-Italy.

[image: Colpevole! Box cover]

[image: Colpevole! Game elements]

[image: Colpevole! Board]

[Video of gameplay (in Italian)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh4xlgCr7VU)

Comment: Has this game been released in German? You noted it was released in English, but the question was about a game that has been released in German. If this game was only printed in Italian, it can't be the game OP was asking about.

Comment: No, Andrew did not understand correctly. In my question it is written that I am looking for an English version of this game: it may not even be there at all. I didn't note it was released in English. Instead... IT IS the game I'm asking for!!!

Comment: As for Robert Miller ... Congratulations !!! You discovered the ... Guilty! It is obviously ... ME! In fact, I've only been told that there is a German version of this game, but it may not even exist at all. For now,  its existence in Italian only has been ascertained, but it is already very much. So,I really  thank you. The question, however, concerns the possible presence of this game in an English version, which by now does not seem to exist, apparently ...On the contrary: it has been ascertained that the game in an English version does not exist!

Comment: @Andrew : I repeat myself : «... customer agent. This agent did some research and found that the game Colpevole! has not been translated to English.»

Comment: @RobertMiller No where did you mention that the game exists in any language except Italian - which doesn't really address OP's comment "in a German edition, the game is titled: „Schuldig!“"

It is what they were looking for, but I'd say you have to cover that the version they were talking about, a german one, exists to show that this is that game.

Comment: Not, I explained in the comment above that the alleged German version - "Schuldig!" - in reality it does not exist. Miller understood this too, it is useless to continue

Comment: I translated the presentation of the game into English, as it is on the game box on the front. This is what you can read (in Italian) from the photos of the game that Andrew Miller has provided. 
I also included it as a game guidance in the "colpevole" ' s tag explanation.

Comment: Here it is:-"A crime has been committed, apparently without explanation; but investigators know the identity of the Guilty. Although his alibi may appear iron, investigations focus on him to find out how and why he came to make his gesture. The analysis of the coroner, the testimony of friends, relatives or simple acquaintances, and the finding of some clues, apparently insignificant, will nail him to his responsibilities. But watch out for time, because every minute that passes brings the guilty closer to victory".

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin : A small correction : My name is RobertMiller, not «Andrew Miller»...

Comment: Oh, please excuse me, you're right,Robert Miller... in these days I easily get confused. Since [@Andrew participated in this post too, I must have confused your names for a moment. I'm sorry. I tried to assign you the 100 rep points for the bounty, as expected; but someone here in SE  disabled my account, and the operation was not successful. Currently, I am unaware of any reasons that led to such an extreme negative decision against me ... soon I will try at least to know what the reasons are for such a decision. See you soon.

Comment: Can anyone explain why I was disabled? What "crime" did I commit this time? I'm the "Colpevole!", ok, but what's the crime? I would have done well to assign the bounty to Robert Miller straight away, as I thought. But "someone" wanted to give misleading information, as usual ... please, could someone here in SE explain me the reasons for this negative decision? Where's the problem with assigning a bounty? Is this the reason?

Comment: Ah ok ... the bounty has been correctly assigned to Robert. But it still remains to explain the wording "user was removed" that appears in the list of my operations ... what does it mean? Please someone make me understand.Thank you.

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin: I had the same message and 10 reputation points were removed from my account. (I did however receive your gift of 100 points - Danke nochmal). Here is the explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed